# Google+ connection statistics shows different numbers

Tags: google-plus

On my Google+ profile page I have 13 connections in the "Have Miyo in circles (13)" but on Circles pages, under "People who've added you" shows 25 connections.

Since there is no way Google+ guys have the time to answer such a question, do any of you experience the same missmatch in connection count?

I assume it's caching related, but, the numbers don't seem to change in days.

Comment: You can answer your own question in a few minutes. Just edit out the link and repost when the time allows in about an hour.

Answer (score 4):

Given the disparity in numbers, it's possible that you've been blocked by some people. They would still count as having added you even if that means adding you to the list of people they don't want any interaction from.

Here's an excerpt from the block help from Google Plus that leans towards that theory:

> #### [Block someone](http://www.google.com/support/+/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1257347&answer=1047934)
>
> - They'll be removed from any circles of yours that they appear in.
> - They'll be removed from your extended circles even if you have mutual connections.
>
> When you block someone, we won't proactively notify them. But since blocking someone limits the interactions that person can have with you, they may figure out that they've been blocked.

Circles in Google+ are asymmetric and private. You can't know what circle(s) you've been put in by other people and whether or not they're actively blocking you. But you will know if they've "added" you.

Where you end up is for them to know and you to scratch your head about.

On further [noodling given your link](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/7ELto0rp2-M/discussion), people can actively limit who sees who else is in their circles.

You can set this when you edit your profile and click the Circles section in the sidebar. You'll see the following options:

> #### In your circles
>
> ☑ Show people in: All circles (lets you check/uncheck which circle counts are publicly displayed)
>
> Who can see this?
>
> - Anyone on the web
> - Your circles
>
> #### Have you in circles
>
> ☑ Show people who have added you to circles

Both can affect the mismatch count between the "in circles" and "people who have added you" count.